# How to handle empty collections and nested collections in assemble?

Tags: assemble

I'm trying to build a static site with a side bar menu depending on two nested collections.
If a collection is empty, it should branch to the next one, or to the final page loop. If none are empty, it should nest both collections before the final page loop.

I'm stuck with the following code, witch triggers a `Warning: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined Use --force to continue.` in assemble. As a newbe in assemble as well as nodejs eco system i may surely have missed something.

Would somebody give me hand in resolving this issue ?
Many thanks in advance for your help.

Kindest regards.

Gruntfile.js snippet:

```
assemble: {
  options: {
    collections: [{
        name: 'domaines',
        inflection: 'domaine'
      },{
        name: 'projets',
        inflection: 'projet'
      }],
   ...
```

Main loop for the aside.hbs partial (snippet) :

```
<div class="aside">
{{#empty domaines}}
  {{> sub-nav-projets }}
{{else}}
  <!-- domaines -->
  <ul class="sub-nav">
  {{#each domaines}}
    <li>{{domaine}}
      {{> sub-nav-projets }}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
  <!-- /domaines -->
{{/empty}}
</div><!--/.aside -->
```

sub-nav-projets.hbs :

```
{{#empty projets}}
  {{> sub-nav }}
{{else}}
  <!-- projets -->
  <ul class="sub-nav">
  {{#each projets}}
    <li>{{projet}}
      {{> sub-nav }}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  <!-- /projets -->
{{/empty}}
```

And finally sub-nav.hbs :

```
  <ul class="sub-nav">
    <!-- you can exclude pages using \{{#isnt}} helper: \{{#isnt data.title 'Blog'}} -->
    {{#withSort pages "data.title"}}
      <li{{#if this.isCurrentPage}} class="active"{{/if}}>
        <a href="{{relative ../page.dest this.dest}}">{{ relative ../page.dest this.dest }} ({{tags}})</a>
      </li>
    {{/withSort}}
  </ul>
  <!-- /.sub-nav -->
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue with the level of the context you're in. You can try adding `../` to different places to see if you can get to the correct context, or change up your partials so you can pass a specific context into them like: `{{> sub-nav-projets ../projets }}`

It's difficult to tell without seeing the entire context you're working with at the start.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your collection is undefined.  Are you sure you added pages to the collection, not just the Gruntfile configuration?  I did the following brief experiment:

```
{{#empty bogus}}
  <p>bogus is empty</p>
{{else}}
  <p>bogus is not empty</p>
{{/empty}}
```

Where `bogus` is undefined and never mentioned anywhere else.  I get the same error "Warning: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". It appears `{{#empty}}` requires a length.  You could work around this problem by wrapping `{{#empty}}` with `{{#if}}`:

```
{{#if bogus}}
    {{#empty bogus}}
        <p>bogus is empty</p>
    {{else}}
        <p>bogus is not empty</p>
    {{/empty}}
{{else}}
    <p>bogus is undefined</p>
{{/if}}
```

But ultimately you need to get pages in your collections.  I recommend you create some simpler structures in a test page, just to make sure you can iterate through your collections and hit each branch of structures like `{{#empty}}`.

Answer (score 0):

### Reformulating the question

**Many thank's for your answers doowb & James Wing**
Unfortunately, snippet is gone in the mean time.
I'm trying to generate an aside menu (three level) for listing all pages links (like a leveled site map). It might match a directory tree for simplicity. But in my current level of skill, I don't even know the way to organize that. The menu should show:

```
Level1 list             Level2 (nested list)           Level3 (nested sub list)
Domains titles          Sections titles (no link)      Only pages links
(link to the index      or pages links if no Section         
 page of the domain)
```

Example:

- Stories (link to introduction page for stories)

  - Portraits (title of section - no link)

    - Marie (page)
    - Peter (page)
  - Mountains (title of section - no link)

    - Bike (page)
    - Mont-Blanc (page)
  - Lake Placid (page)
  - Triangles (page)
- Photo (link to introduction page for photo)

  - ...

I played around with many assembles options and structures variations unsuccessful (flatten, cwd, expand, partials, nested partials, directory tree, collections...). 
Actually, my best draft generate the list in flat form, complete and correctly ordered, but without hierarchical tree organization like in the example above.

kindest regards